# How can i get text inside time tag using Pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a two time tags in my code .
I have to simply get text inside second time tag.

```js
var children=document.getElementByClassName("entry-date published").textContent;
document.write(children);
```

```html
<time class="updated" datetime="2022-09-14T00:54:04+05:30" itemprop="dateModified">14th September 2022</time>
<time class="entry-date published" datetime="2022-02-09T18:35:52+05:30" itemprop="datePublished">9th February 2022</time></span> <span class="byline">
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What do you mean by "get text inside second time tag"?

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can use;

```
const requestedTime=document.querySelector(".entry-date")?.value;
```

"." uses for class names, if you have "example" class you should define it as ".example"

"?" called as Optional chaining that means if there is no object like that return "undefined" not an error

".value" uses for getting value (if there is one more object has same class it'll return error.)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Yo, thank you for the `?.` part! I code in JS like a year or two, but I haven't seen such a thing! Very useful!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `getElementByClassName` method, only `getElementsByClassName`. So you would have to change your code to `.getElementsByClassName(...)[0]`.

```js
var children=document.getElementsByClassName("entry-date published")[0].textContent
console.log(children);
```

```html
<time class="updated" datetime="2022-09-14T00:54:04+05:30" itemprop="dateModified">14th September 2022</time>
<time class="entry-date published" datetime="2022-02-09T18:35:52+05:30" itemprop="datePublished">9th February 2022</time></span> <span class="byline">
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

1. First there is a type in `getElementByClassName` it should be `getElementsByClassName` with `s`.
2. `getElementsByClassName` will return `HTMLCollection` which is `array-like`, I suggest you to use `querySelector` instead because you want to select just one element.

```js
var text = document.querySelector(".entry-date.published").textContent;
alert(text)
```

```html
<time class="updated" datetime="2022-09-14T00:54:04+05:30" itemprop="dateModified">14th September 2022</time>
<time class="entry-date published" datetime="2022-02-09T18:35:52+05:30" itemprop="datePublished">9th February 2022</time></span> <span class="byline">
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a **2nd** child, you can use `:nth-child(2)`. So your code would be something like this:

```js
document.write(document.querySelector("time:nth-child(2)").textContent);
```

Learn more about CSS selectors on **[CSS Diner](https://flukeout.github.io/)**